# getActionView returns null with searchview

Tags: android, eclipse, searchview

Trying to get searchview to work on app.

sdk min 17 max 22

testing on emulator api 18

menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">    
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/search" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search" 
        android:title="@string/search_title" 
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" 
        android:orderInCategory="200" 
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView">        
    </item> 
    <item android:id="@+id/scan" 
        android:title="@string/scan" 
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="300">        
    </item>   
</menu>
```

onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.material_toolbar, menu);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {           
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            materialUpdate();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Running debug and looking at the search menu item shows action as null.

The layout display shows the android.support.v7.widget.SearchView as unknown xml attribute.

I am using Eclipse instead of Android Studio on this project.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Proguard or minify(ing) your code at some way?

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58508

When you use a minify method like Proguard, classes and methods that you not access directly (but by some declarative way or reflexion) are removed. To avoid this, you need to instruct the build to specifically keep this classes/methods.

In this case, the SearchView class can be removed, because isn't directly called.

Try add this on your proguard rules file (check the right filename on your gradle file, at getDefaultProguardFile):

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Saved me a lot of trouble! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I added a SearchView to my menu (this is inside a Fragment):

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    final MenuItem item = menu.add("Search");
    item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    final SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getActivity());
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    item.setActionView(mSearchView);
}
```

As an aside, I'd also recommend making the switch to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You are using support library. Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search));
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what was wrong with what I had. It all appeared to be logical. I suspect that I had some misspelling are xmlns that was not correct. But it works the way I have it.

I appreciate the help but recommend that answers explain what you believe the problem is, what the fix is and why. It really helps the person learn.

MenuItemCompat is helper for accessing features in MenuItem introduced after API level 4 in a backwards compatible fashion. It is not necessary for this scenario.

Please keep answering questions it really does help

Thanks